# Limit transparency to single layer for multiple objects

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to make a group of foreground objects transparent as a single entity, where they occlude each other like solid objects and then have transparency applied after, instead of each individual one having its own transparency.

There is an option in the material settings called Show Backface, but that only works for single objects. Is there a way to apply this effect for a group of objects? Merging shouldn't be an option as the foreground may also contain rigged characters and such. The objects in the screenshots below are only to demonstrate what I mean.

I also thought about compositing the foreground and background together as separate layers, but then I run into a problem of the background not containing shadows of the foreground (and vice versa), or if I render foreground + background as one layer and only background as second layer, then the shadows occluded by the foreground will start fading out too. Another thing I thought about was duplicating the whole foreground and giving everything a fully transparent material to render the background with shadows, but I'd rather avoid duplicating anything.

Is something like this possible? Compositor solutions are also welcome.

Transparency of each individual objects, not what I want.
[image: Transparency of each individual objects, not what I want.]

Transparency of a group as a whole, I want this.
[image: Transparency of a group as a whole, I want this.]

Comment: I'm afraid it does come down to duplicating your objects, because you need one set of them being transparent and casting shadows, and another set to actually render. Been trying some setups, and that's the best I could do, too. Also, just curios why the top result is undesired? It looks more realistic to be honest.

Comment: It's for a scene where a character is very close to a camera and you still need to see what's behind him. The problem is, my characters are modular, being composed of various parts like body, face, hair, clothing and accessories, like in a game with deep character customization, and it just looks wrong seeing every object being transparent individually.

Comment: I see. I think the best you can do with eevee is after you deem your scene ready for rendering, duplicate your character's objects, and have one view layer where they're invisible to the camera so they're still casting shadows, and another layer where the background is disabled and your character is opaque, and comp them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found another solution by random using geometry nodes, which doesn't require setting up any extra view layers or doing anything in the compositor.

### Individual Object Method

- Add geometry nodes to one of the objects (or you can create a
  new empty one just for this purpose)
- Link in all other objects using **Object Info** node (also switch to **Relative** so they keep their position)
- Merge them together using the **Join Geometry** node
- Hide the actual objects, that you merged, from the scene
- Don't forget to turn off **Show Backface** in material settings for your materials

[image: Individual Object Method]

[image: Outliner]

### Collection Method

- Put all of your objects into a collection
- Create a new object outside the collection with geometry nodes
- Link the collection objects using **Collection Info** node
- Run it through **Realize Instances** node
- Disable the collection from view layer
- Don't forget to turn off **Show Backface** in material settings for your materials

[image: Collection Method]

[image: Outliner]

### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

### **Compositing Eevee**

- enable **Shadow pass**
- change Cubes material setup of *Alpha* mode to **Blend**.
- create *View Layer* for

  - Foreground objects
  - Background object
  - and one for all objects to composit Shadow pass

[image]

**The trick here is Alpha Blend mode in material.** Objects with Alpha Blend are not visible for Shadow pass ... technically Im not advanced in this area to explane WHY ... I dont even know if it is bug, missing feature or intended ... it just works like that. So if someone has an explanation for it - please dont hasitate to edit my answer (or create a new one).

[image]

It is still a mistery how this result can be helpful, but I guess that is what you asked for :)

[image]

---

### **Compositing Cycles**

Under *Outliner > Filter* enable *Holdout* and *Indirect Only*
and use them in a way as shown on screenshots for each View Layer ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this work with eevee though? I tried it and the *Indirect Only* features seems to not work with it. OP tagged eevee that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yep, I thought about this, but sadly it doesn't work in Eeevee. Hopefully they'll make it work at least for shadows one day, like they did with holdout.

Comment: @Jack check the edit ... it should cover your Q now.

Comment: Wow, that's a very nice trick. Thanks! Anyway, you can read what it's intended for in a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Material-only Eevee solution:

[image]

Only a single layer of refracting ojects will be rendered by Eevee, so use refraction (1.0 IOR, 0.0 roughness) instead of transparency and enable screen space refraction.  Full shadows, single layer transparency without compositing or geo nodes.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution! Though that also means I need to enable screen space reflections right? I'm doing NPR and I use glossy shaders to create speculars from lamps and I'd rather avoid other objects reflecting on those.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you'd need that-- but if you don't want to use it for anything else, you might be able to get away with reducing the max roughness on the screen space reflections.

Comment: That's a good tip, I usually use something higher than 0 and then sharpen it with ramps. Thanks.